# Windows XP SP3 Reboots automatically every 1.5 -2 hours

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

I had a problem with ALURERON virus and I was trying to fix it and I deleted some registry enries for services in current control settings by mistake and now Windows XP restarts by itself every 1.5 -2 hours. but in safe mode it does not restart.

(By the way i finally deleted the virus with Kasperky killer programme.)

Also Explorer continually crashes complaining about flash.ocx , ntdll.dll or icm.dll modules.

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your only sensible option is as follows:

1. Copy all your important data off the hard disk to what ever external storage you have available. (USB Hard Disk, DVD-R, etc). Using a utility such as [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) will probably help if your computer keep rebooting half way through
2. Locate your installation media for Windows XP
3. Obliterate the partitions on your computer
4. Reinstall the operating system
5. Fully patch the OS and ensure you install AV software on your PC, ensure the AV software definitions are up to date
6. Install any other software you need
7. Attach the storage media with your backup files, but don't open any files just yet!
8. Perform a full scan of your backed up data using your AV software
9. Assuming all is free from infection, copy the files you need back to your freshly installed computer